# Importing scala sbt project to Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I have downloaded github project which have spark scala code and build it using sbt. I am trying to import the project to below version of Scala IDE. But I do not see the option to import sbt or scala project. How can I import it?

> Scala IDE build of Eclipse SDK
>
> Build id: 4.1.0-vfinal-20150704-2326-Typesafe

Answer (score 2):

Use plug-ins that can generate Eclipse project files out of the sbt project definition.

- sbt 0.7.x, use eclipsify
- sbt 0.12.x, use sbteclipse

Add the plugin to project/plugins.sbt file.
 example: `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")`

Run `sbt eclipse`